# search a word by key enter

Tags: javafx, key, enter, pressed

i have a problem with my searching method.

With this method, I can enter a word in the textfield and display the word in the textarea. However, this only happens once if i let it run. I need to expand it so, that every time I click on "enter," the program should continue with searching in the textarea. How can i do this?
And please give me code examples. i have only 2 days left for my presentation.

Thanks a lot for the helps

```
textfield.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER)  {
                String text = textarea.getText();

              Labeled errorText = null;
            if (textfield.getText() != null && !textfield.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    index = textarea.getText().indexOf(textfield.getText()); 
                    textarea.getText();

                    if (index == -1) {
                        errorText.setText("Search key Not in the text");
                    } else {
                      //  errorText.setText("Found");
                        textarea.selectRange(index, index + textfield.getLength());

                        }


                    }   

                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [overloaded version of the `indexOf` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,int)) allowing you to search starting at a specific index. Keep track of the index of your last find and start searching from this position:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    TextField textField = new TextField("foo");
    TextArea textarea = new TextArea();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        textarea.appendText("foo\nbarfoobarfoofoo\n");
    }

    textField.setOnAction(evt -> {
        String searchText = textField.getText();
        if (searchText.isEmpty()) {
            return; // searching for empty text doesn't make sense
        }
        int index = textarea.getSelection().getEnd();

        // in case of the first search, start at the beginning
        // TODO: adjust condition/starting index according to needs
        if (textarea.getSelection().getLength() == 0) {
            index = 0;
        }

        // find next occurrence
        int newStartIndex = textarea.getText().indexOf(searchText, index);

        // mark occurrence
        if (newStartIndex >= 0) {
            textarea.selectRange(newStartIndex, newStartIndex + searchText.length());
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(textField, textarea));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

#### Edit

If you are not satisfied with searching the element after the selection ( or after the cursor, if there is no range selected), you could save the data of the end of the last match:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    TextField textField = new TextField("foo");
    TextArea textarea = new TextArea();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        textarea.appendText("foo\nbarfoobarfoofoo\n");
    }

    class SearchHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
        int index = 0;

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            String searchText = textField.getText();
            String fullText = textarea.getText();

            if (index + searchText.length() > fullText.length()) {
                // no more matches possible
                // TODO: notify user
                return;
            }
            // find next occurrence
            int newStartIndex = textarea.getText().indexOf(searchText, index);

            // mark occurrence
            if (newStartIndex >= 0) {
                index = newStartIndex + searchText.length();
                textarea.selectRange(newStartIndex, index);
            } else {
                index = fullText.length();
                // TODO: notify user
            }
        }

    }

    SearchHandler handler = new SearchHandler();
    textField.setOnAction(handler);
    // reset index to search from start when changing the text of the TextField
    textField.textProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> handler.index = 0);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(textField, textarea));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to help if either the text or the selection changes between calls - or what do I overlook?

Comment: @kleopatra Many text editors start the search just after the selected range. The OP how exactly the program should behave... Of course you can save the data about the last match somewhere. I added some code to the answer to enlighten you.